# Adding existing functions to a class as methods

Tags: typescript, es6-class

I have two examples one I have a group of functions like this:

```
const funcs = () => {
    const foo = (t: string) => `${t} meow`
    const bar = (t: string) => `${t} woof`
    return { foo, bar }
}
```

The other is just a stand alone function:

```
const foo = (t: string) => `${t} meow`
```

How can I add these to an existing class:

```
class Example {

}
```

I'm open to decorators, ideally I don't have to open up the constructor.

Comment: what about doing it `bar = foo;` like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=41#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMCMC8MAUBKdA+GAbwFgAoGCmUSWOEEdLKALhmgCcBLMAc1zQIADACSEoAXxgBbAKYgA7oLKUq4aDABGAQ3aNMLNlC69+Q0RJjz6cJeUrsZUBOzBF49ADSadMcWXEA3GRk1Op0DBj6rBzcfPgwImKSsgqCQaQhADZaEKgAogAeWlIADpkyRMqU2roY4el+GaShIOUAdJkgPJhgMvIwhcVlMjhtNZgARAAWMpmdE9jYAUA.

Comment: What do you mean by adding function to new class? Do you want to use them and do you want to define them in new class?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you would be able to add those methods at the run time by adding it to the prototype of Example

```
const funcs = () => {
    const foo = (t: string) => `${t} meow`
    const bar = (t: string) => `${t} woof`
    return { foo, bar }
};

class Example {
    [prop: string]: any;
}

let fns:{[prop: string]: any;} = funcs();

for (let key of Object.keys(fns)) {
    let fn = fns[key];
    Example.prototype[key] = fn;
}

console.log(new Example().bar("hello"));
```

The crux for this way is that these methods are added at runtime. So, the typescript compiler doesn't know they even exist in example's prototype.

I think that this isn't something we shoud do if we're using typescript because typescript's sole purpose is to check stuff at compile time.

I believe the best way is to refractor it if you're using typescript.